# Windows script file- Microsoft JScript runtime error: Type mismatch

Tags: com, runtime-error, jscript, type-mismatch, wsh

I am trying to run a "pre-built" .wsf file which seems to work perfectly fine for my colleagues. But, I seem to be getting the error:

> "D:\startup.wsf(221, 8) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Type mismatch"

```
var QXDM;
var PortNumber = -1;
//QXDM object was created using ""new ActiveXObject( "QXDM.Application" );""
//input received from user for PortNumber and parsed
PortNumber = WScript.Arguments( 0 );
if (PortNumber != -1)
   {
       // Change the port
       QXDM.COMPort= PortNumber;  ///////LINE:221 ERROR HERE
   }
```

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: In your example, `PortNumber` seems to be a string, not a number. Try something like `QXDM.COMPort = parseInt(PortNumber);`

Comment: Hi Igor, Thank you for that suggestion. The problem was that PortNumber was never assigned a value as it was read wrong. The value stayed as -1 and hence the issue. It is fixed now.